# Problems with XPath in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to find element based on it attributes.

I have already tried searching by all divs, and specify by attributes, and even searching by *. None of this was solution.
Whole element looks like this:

```
<div class="charc" data-lvl="66" data-world="walios" data-nick="mirek">
```

This is my search expression:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-world="walios"] and [@data-nick="mirek"]')
```

I would like to find this element using python with selenium, and be able to click on it.

Actually I am getting the error

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@data-world="walios"] and [@data-nick="mirek"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use mutliple attributes in xpath, here is the general notation `//tag[@attribute1='attribute1_val' and @attribute2='attribute_val2']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is correct because your predicate(s) is/are not correct.
Try putting the predicate in one `[...]` expression:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-world="walios" and @data-nick="mirek"]')
```

Comment: ...or you can just remove the `and` to give `//div[@data-world="walios"][@data-nick="mirek"]`.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-world="walios" and @data-nick="mirek)]")`

or

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-world="walios"][@data-nick="mirek)]")`

The multiple conditions for selecting the  tag can't be within nested []. Either you have to specify within one [] or within multiple []s.

**XPath axes methods:**

These XPath axes methods are used to find the complex or dynamic elements. Below we will see some of these methods.

XPath expression select nodes or list of nodes on the basis of attributes like ID , Name, Classname, etc. from the XML document .